# Show all products image and name in order history page in opencart 3

Tags: php, opencart, opencart-3

I want to show product details/get all products images names inside an order in order history, to achieve the same I have inserted my code inside a result loop just like the below code but it is fetching only one product and that same product is visible to each orders.

1.catalog/controller/account/order.php

```
public function index() {
...
foreach ($results as $result) {
...

//for product for loop

            $order_info = $this->model_account_order->getOrder($result['order_id']);

            if ($order_info) {
            $this->load->model('catalog/product');
            $this->load->model('tool/upload');



            // Products


            $data['products'] = array();

            $products = $this->model_account_order->getOrderProducts($result['order_id']);

            foreach ($products as $product) {
                $option_data = array();

                $options = $this->model_account_order->getOrderOptions($result['order_id'], $product['order_product_id']);

                foreach ($options as $option) {
                    if ($option['type'] != 'file') {
                        $value = $option['value'];
                    } else {
                        $upload_info = $this->model_tool_upload->getUploadByCode($option['value']);

                        if ($upload_info) {
                            $value = $upload_info['name'];
                        } else {
                            $value = '';
                        }
                    }

                    $option_data[] = array(
                        'name'  => $option['name'],
                        'value' => (utf8_strlen($value) > 20 ? utf8_substr($value, 0, 20) . '..' : $value)
                    );
                }

                $product_info = $this->model_catalog_product->getProduct($product['product_id']);

                if ($product_info) {
                    $reorder = $this->url->link('account/order/reorder', 'order_id=' . $result['order_id'] . '&order_product_id=' . $product['order_product_id'], true);
                } else {
                    $reorder = '';
                }

                $data['products'][] = array(
                    'name'     => $product['name'],
                    'model'    => $product['model'],
                    'option'   => $option_data,
                    'quantity' => $product['quantity'],
                    'price'    => $this->currency->format($product['price'] + ($this->config->get('config_tax') ? $product['tax'] : 0), $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']),
                    'total'    => $this->currency->format($product['total'] + ($this->config->get('config_tax') ? ($product['tax'] * $product['quantity']) : 0), $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']),
                    'reorder'  => $reorder,
                    'return'   => $this->url->link('account/return/add', 'order_id=' . $result['order_id'] . '&product_id=' . $product['product_id'], true)
                );

                // Totals
                $data['totals'] = array();

                $totals = $this->model_account_order->getOrderTotals($result['order_id']);

                    foreach ($totals as $total) {
                    $data['totals'][] = array(
                        'title' => $total['title'],
                        'text'  => $this->currency->format($total['value'], $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']),
                    );
                }




            }

            //end for loop of product
            }
}
```

2. order-list.twig
   SCREENSHOT HERE :

[image]

3. Front Page( Order History)
   SCREESHOT :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your loop. You are attaching the product to $data['products'], when you should be attaching it to $data['orders']['products']

1. in your code rename the variable

```php
    $data['products']
```

to

```php
    $order_products
```

2. then add this to the order array

```php
    $data['orders'][] = array(
        ...
        'order_products' => $order_products
        ...
    );
```

3. and in the twig file change the for loop

```
    {% for order_product in order.order_products %}
    <li>{{ order_product.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
```

Basically, what we are doing is extending the orders object to include the products info and then we are displaying it in the view.

Comment: @Hi Dmitry,
Thanks for the quick response,
I followed your instruction but i am getting blank result um! I got one doubt you want me to replace $data['products'] array with a variable $order_products?

Comment: After looking deep i saw one tiny mistake in your loop and i have fixed it's working absolutely fine. You are awesome thanks alot.
Here is the working for loop for the twig. 
**'{% for order_product in order.order_products %}
                     {{order_product.name}}
                     {{order_product.quantity}}
                  {% endfor %}'**

Comment: Yeah, you are right, had this key `products_info` first then decided to rename it to something better. will correct the answer. enjoy! checkout my youtube channel for more tips at https://youtube.com/dreamvention

Comment: I am a big Fan of Dreamvention, i am so lucky i got reply from a member of dreamvention. And i subbed your channel.

Comment: Great to hear that. Thanks! We are finally getting out in the open and sharing more on social media, but its really hard cause we are more code rats. Glad I could help